# cannot import name HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
from django import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world ! ")
```

---

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name HttpResponse
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can try this: `from django.http import HttpResponse`

Comment: How can I added this in urlpatterns !

Answer (score 9):

You are importing from wrong location

[django.http](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/HttpResponse#HttpResponse) this is right location `from django.http import HttpResponse`

Answer (score 0):

Changing from django to django.http in the views.py file works in most cases, if it doesn't check the urls.py file in the project dir and make sure that :

1. the path() to your view is imported correctly
2. that it is above the path('admin/', admin.site.urls) in the urlpatterns list